# Would $x_1^2 + x_2^2 = 0$ be considered an equation for a linear subspace of $\mathbb{R}^2$?

Tags: linear-algebra

I understand the equation satisfies the subspace containing the zero vector however I don't know how to interpret the squares on $x_1$ and $x_2$. Can anybody explain to me the difference it makes, if any, that the terms are squared?

Comment: The only solution to the equation is the single point (0,0), which happens to be a (0-dimensional) subspace, although the equation is not a "linear equation." Without the squares it is a linear equation which defines a one dimensional subspace.

Comment: I consider it to be basically a coincidence that the result is a subspace. Indeed, to consider linear combinations: if $x_1^2 + x_2^2 = 0$ and $y_1^2 + y_2^2 = 0$ then $(x_1+y_1)^2 + (x_y+y_2)^2 = 2(x_1 y_1 + x_2 y_2)$, which has no reason to be $0$ except for the incidental fact that we already know that $x_1 = x_2 = 0$.

Answer (score 0):

The equation 
$$
x_1^2+x_2^2=0
$$
has one solution, $x_1=x_2=0$. This is the trivial subspace of $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Answer (score 0):

If the terms were not squared, $x_1 + x_2 = 0$ would define a line $x_1 = -x_2$. However, since the terms are squared, both terms are forced to be $0$, so the subspace is the zero subspace (which is, in fact, a linear subspace).